# Discord.js need help TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried testing discord.js v13 and I came across an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

The code

```js
const { Message, Client, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu } = require('discord.js');
    
module.exports = {
  name: "testselect",
  description: "Test command for select",
  category: "test",
  execute(client, message, args, Discord) {

    const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
      new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId('test-select')
        .setPlaceholder('Test Placeholder')
        .addOptions([
          {
            label: 'Test Label',
            description: 'Test Description',
            value: 'test_value',
            emoji: '',
          }
        ])
    )
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Test title for select embed")
    .setDescription("hello")

    message.channel.send({ content: "Test content", embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `message` is not a real `Message` object. In your execution, make sure the arguments get passed in correctly

```js
someVar.execute(client, message, args, Discord)
```

`someVar` is your required (using `require()`) command file. Usually the variable is named `command` but not always.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct (when you can) if it helped

Comment: i fell embarrassed for seeing that i only needed to change places XD

Comment: Don’t worry; I’ve seen tons of questions with this exact problem.

Comment: You can now mark the answer as correct if it helped -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69019713/discord-js-need-help-typeerror-cannot-read-property-send-of-undefined#comment121983099_69019793